# How do you mock ORM model query in your unit test?

Tags: python, unit-testing, orm

In my case I have a func like below:

```
# the ModelA is an ORM model here (peewee)

def my_func():
    result1 = ModelA.select().where( 
        # some condition here
    )
    result2 = ModelA.select().where(
        # some other condition here 
    )
    
    # use the combination of result1 and 2 to do some thing and return result
```

I do not know how to mock the query here. There are two problems:

1. I do not know how to mock the query. Some article said:

   mock.patch(some_path.ModelA) as mock_model
   mock_model.select.where.return_value = the value I expected

which is not working

2. even I know how to write the mock. There are two queries against the same model.
   So I guess I can only mock one result

One way to solve is that two query into two func. But I can not see any beneficial except easy for ut

Comment: which ORM are you using?

Comment: peewee ORM model

Comment: Typically people do not try to mock the db, but use a test-only db or sqlite in-memory database - simply because of the complexity involved.